# Solve for $x$ in $\frac{\log_4x}{1-\log_4x}\le 1$

Tags: calculus

$\frac{\log_4x}{1-\log_4x}\le 1$

I did:

$$\frac{\log_4x}{1-\log_4x}\le 1 \Leftrightarrow \log_4{x} \le 1-\log_4{x} \Leftrightarrow \log_4{x} \le \log_4(4)-\log_4{x} \Leftrightarrow \log_4x \le \log_4(\frac{4}{x})\\ \Leftrightarrow x \le \frac{4}{x} \Leftrightarrow x^2 \le 4 \Leftrightarrow x \le 2$$

Since $x$ has to be greater than zero because of logarithms, part of the solution is $]0;2]$

But then I checked in wolframalpha and it seems I missed something:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7Blog_4x%7D%7B1-log_4x%7D%5Cle+1

The solution is $]0;+2]\cup]4;+\infty[ $

But I am not sure of how to find that second part, that $x$ must be greater than 4.

I know that $x$ and to be *different* from 4, otherwise $\frac{log_4x}{1-log_4x}$ would be impossible. What I don't understand is how to find out that $x$ has to be *greater*, not just different, from 4 by analytical methods.

Can someone explain to me how to get the solution of this analitically?

Comment: When you multiply by $1 - \log_4 x$ at the first step, that either keeps or reverses the inequality depending on the sign of the quantity you multiplied by. So you have two subcases to work out.

Comment: If $x \gt 4$ then $\log_4 x \gt 1$ so $1-\log_4 x \lt 0$ so $\dfrac{\log_4 x}{1-\log_4}\lt 0 \lt 1$

Comment: @dxiv What do you mean by "the sign of the quantity you multiplied by"? It  will always be positive, because 1 is positive, right?

Comment: The sign of $1 - \log_4 x$. If it's $\gt 0$ then the inequality is preserved. If it's $\lt 0$ then it's reversed.

Comment: @dxiv Ah, I see

Comment: I would first start with writing $u=\log_4 x$ and solve the inequality for $u$. Then $\frac{u}{1-u}=\frac{1}{1-u}-1\leq 1\iff \frac{1}{1-u}\leq 2\iff 1-u<0 \text{ or } 1-u\geq \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\log_4 x$ and the you want:

$$1\geq \frac{u}{1-u} = \frac{1}{1-u}-1$$
Which means you want $\frac{1}{1-u}\leq 2$, so either $1-u<0$ or $1-u\geq \frac{1}{2}$. This gives $u>1$ or $u\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

One last step to get the result for $x$.

Comment: How does $\frac{u}{1-u}$ become $\frac{1}{1-u} -1 $?

Comment: Wait nevermind, I got it

Comment: Actually no, I still don't understand how $\frac{u}{1-u}$ becomes $\frac{1}{1-u} -1$. I assumed it was because you subtracted 1 but then I get $0 \ge \frac{u}{1-u}-1 \Leftrightarrow 0 \ge \frac{-1}{1-u}$. Could you explain?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-u}-1=\frac{1}{1-u}-\frac{1-u}{1-u}=\frac{1-(1-u)}{1-u}=\frac{u}{1-u}$. This has nothing to do with the inequality, it's just an equality. They are equal.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply by $(1-\log_4 x)^2$ instead, because this is always positive and doesn't interfere with the direction of the inequality (this is a neat trick to get rid of denominators):
$$\log_4(x)(1-\log_4(x))\leq(1-\log_4(x))^2$$
$$[\log_4(x)-(1-\log_4(x))](1-\log_4(x))\leq 0$$
$$(2\log_4(x)-1)(1-\log_4(x))\leq 0$$
Now you just have to look at the signs of $2\log_4(x)-1$ and $1-\log_4(x)$. The first is positive when $x\geq 2$ and negative elsewhere, and the second is positive when $x\leq 4$ and negative elsewhere. Thus the product is $\leq 0$ when $0<x\leq 2$ or $x\geq 4$. However in the initial equation there is a denominator $1-\log_4(x)$, so the original term is not defined at $x=4$, so the solution is in fact $0<x\leq 2$ or $x>4$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I noticed that right away, deleted the question (to hide it) and corrected it already ;)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Corrected. Thanks for noticing